# Can I use one class category extension .h and .m file for iOS and OSX?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, objective-c-category

Is there a way to have one header and implementation file for both OSX categories and iOS categories? I don't want to make the methods the exact same and add another two files.

I've tried this, which doesn't work:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#define kClass [UIColor class]
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#elif TARGET_OS_MAC
#define kClass [NSColor class]
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#endif

@interface kClass (MyCategory)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely! Just remember that `#define` is a simple text replacement before compilation: you want `kClass` to be `UIColor`, not `[UIColor class]`, just as you would never write `@interface [UIColor class] (MyCategory)`.

In conclusion:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#define kClass UIColor
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#elif TARGET_OS_MAC
#define kClass NSColor
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#endif

@interface kClass (MyCategory)
```

Comment: You can see what the preprocessor has done to your file.  In Xcode 5 you can use the Product -> Perform Action -> Preprocess File menu.  This will show you the contents of the file after it has been preprocessed but before it is compiled.  You will be able to see what "simple text replacements" have been made.

Comment: Awesome, this worked! I only had to add this line above all of the others: `#include "TargetConditionals.h"`